# iOS 8 Self Sizing Cells With Accessory View

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, ios8

Using iOS 8.3 simulator and Xcode 6.3.2.

I'm using the self sizing cells technique in iOS 8, and it works terrifically when the cell has no accessory view, but breaks when the cell has an accessory view. I set constraints on the label inside the cell:

[image: UILabel constraints in a UITableViewCell]

Then I use an `estimatedRowHeight` and set the `rowHeight` to `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` (I'm omitting `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` here, but it just returns 3 for this example):

```
@implementation MyTableViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0f;
    self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}

...

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    MyCell *cell = (MyCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"myCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.titleLabel.text = @"Test comment Test comment Test comment Test comment Test comment Test comment Test comment Test comment Test comment Test comment Test comment ";

    return cell;
}

@end
```

And bam, everything looks great:

[image: UITableView looks fine]

But when I add an accessory view in the Storyboard, without changing any of the code:

[image: With accessory view]

the first cell goes to hell. Xcode's view debugger tells me the label height is 1785 points, and I had to use a gif to show it here:

[image: Huge cell]

I do notice that the other two cells are sized fine. I also note that when I rotate the simulator, the first cell gets resized properly, including after it's rotated back to portrait.

Does anyone know why the accessory view messes this up so badly, and what I can do to fix it? A sample project is available at http://github.com/UberJason/SelfSizingNightmare.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug indeed. I have sent your project to Apple. There is a reply from Apple.

[image]

Comment: Cool, I'll check it out in iOS 9 beta 3! I did take a look at it in beta 1 or 2, and it seemed fixed, although self-sizing cells in general could still get a bit wonky at times when working with more complex layouts with more views. Hopefully beta 3 made things rock solid.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be caused by the label inside the cell having `numberOfLines = 0`.

Although I'm not sure why, it looks as though adding the accessory to the cell leaves auto layout unable to calculate the height of the label when the table first loads.

I was able to fix your example by adding a preferred max width to the label - which seems to be enough to let the layout system figure out the height in time:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    MyCell *cell = (MyCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"myCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Give the layout system something to help it estimate the label height    
    cell.titleLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = self.titleLabel.bounds.size.width;
    cell.titleLabel.text = @"Test comment Test comment Test comment Test comment Test comment Test comment Test comment Test comment Test comment Test comment Test comment ";

    return cell;
}
```

Alternatively, calling `[tableView reloadData]` in `viewDidAppear` also seems to fix it.

Comment: I agree that the accessory view causes the problems. Setting the preferredMaxLayoutWidth may help in this case, but I've had other self-sizing cells (with slightly more complicated layouts) with accessory views where that did not help. Also, calling [tableView reloadData] in viewDidAppear does work, but it makes for an ugly user experience because the cells "pop" into place... anyway, this issue seems better resolved in iOS 9 beta, so I'm just deciding not to really worry about it.